# File Download from Azure Blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Below code is for donwnloading file from azure blob. I have problem with .docx,.xlsx files and that too after deployment only, mean in local machine it is working fine.

The problem is after downloading .xlsx or .docx, when i open that file showing file corrupted popup.

```
public void DownloadBlob(string blobName)
{
    //You have to get values for below items from azure
    string accountName = "MyAccName";
    string accountPrimaryKey = "MyKey";
    string blobContainer = "ContainerName";
    CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName, accountPrimaryKey), false);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainer);
    CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    blob.DownloadToStream(memStream);

    Response.ContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + blobName.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (blob.Properties.Length - 1).ToString());
    Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the issue (seems unlikely), but why are you subtracting one from the length? It seems that would chop off the last byte of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you have  issue with your code as As Steve suggested you are setting length incorrectly.

I worked on similar issue sometime last year and documented the solution in my blog as below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/04/05/downloading-word-and-excel-files-from-windows-azure-storage-in-a-asp-net-web-role.aspx